# Gen.sequence ignores size of given Traversable

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalacheck

Gen.sequence seems to be ignoring size of given `Traversable`. Is that by design? I'm using version `1.14.0` with Scala 2.13. Following generator

```
Gen.sequence[List[Int], Int](List.fill(3)(Gen.const(5)))
```

sometimes generates List of size 1. What am I missing ?

Sample test

```
import org.scalacheck.Gen
import org.scalatest.concurrent.ScalaFutures
import org.scalatest.{Assertions, FlatSpec, Inside, Inspectors, Matchers, OptionValues}
import org.scalatestplus.scalacheck.ScalaCheckPropertyChecks

class RuleSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with Assertions with OptionValues with Inside with Inspectors with ScalaFutures with ScalaCheckPropertyChecks {

  val filterGen = Gen.listOfN(3, Gen.const(5))
  val inputGen = Gen.pick(10, 5 to 15).map(_.toList).filter(_.nonEmpty)

  "A HasAny rule with partially matching filter" should "validate input" in {
    forAll(filterGen, inputGen) { case (filter, input) =>
      val result = HasAny(filter: _*).valid(input)
      println(s"$result: $filter   ${input}\n")
      result should be(true)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be due to [Test Case Minimisation](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/blob/master/doc/UserGuide.md#test-case-minimisation)

> One interesting feature of ScalaCheck is that if it finds an argument
>   that falsifies a property, it tries to minimise that argument before
>   it is reported. This is done automatically when you use the
>   `Prop.property` and `Prop.forAll` methods to create properties, but not if
>   you use `Prop.forAllNoShrink`.

Hence try using `Prop.forAllNoShrink` like so

```
Prop.forAllNoShrink(filterGen, inputGen) { case (filter, input) => ...
```

If using ScalaTest's `forAll` then try the suggestion in [Add support for not shrinking values in GeneratorDrivenPropertyChecks #584](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/issues/584) by creating the following trait

```
trait NoShrink {
  implicit def noShrink[A]: Shrink[A] = Shrink(_ => Stream.empty)
}
```

and mix it in the spec like so

```
class RuleSpec extends FlatSpec ... with ScalaCheckPropertyChecks with NoShrink {
  ...
    forAll(filterGen, inputGen) { case (filter, input) => ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately it produces error `No implicit view available from org.scalatest.Assertion => org.scalacheck.Prop.`